# Azure Data Factory Cannot Connect to Azure Cloud Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machine, azure-data-factory

I am receiving a connection failed (cannot connect to SQL Server) while creating a Linked Service in Azure Data Factory.

The SQL Server I have created is a developer licensed SQL Server 2017 which i manually installed on an Azure VM.

I can connect to the sql server via SSMS just fine.

I have tried exposing 1433 to the world thinking that it was a security group issue but it is still failing.

I dont see an option to "Allow access to Azure services" from the portal for a VM.

Building an azure Sql Server isnt an option because of limitations with that version.

the error message just says "Cannot Connect to...." There is nothing in the VM sql server logs or other logs on the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect finally. I used JSON connection formatting this time and again had to expose 1433 publicly.